# How to stop ./configure script?

Tags: command-line, process, job-control

I need to remotely install a program on a Linux computer. I do:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

However I seem to get issues when I run `./configure` (it's a separate problem) where the configuration screen essentially freezes; it doesn't move past a certain check. I need to stop the configuration so I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, and that lets me use the terminal again.

However, it seems to me the process does not stop. I see the `config.log` file continue to grow in bytes (gets to be 40+MB). This is a problem since now the process is ongoing and creating this log file that I don't know to what size it will grow to.

I need to reboot the computer in order to stop the configure script now working in the background. I can't see find it's PID when I use the top command to view the processes.

How can I stop `./configure` script through the terminal successfully?

Comment: have you tried running this from `tmux` or `screen` (often a good idea when working with a remote connection).

Comment: Just do `ps`, look for configure and type `kill PID`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+ <kbd>Z</kbd> suspends ([TSTP/SIGSTOP signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)#Implementation)) the *most recent* foreground process, which returns you back to your shell. From the shell, the `bg`  command sends the suspended process to the background while the `fg` commands brings it back to foreground. Try <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, which sends SIGINT, killing the process. Some software reacts to SIGINT in other ways, like cleaning up before exiting.

Comment: You may add that you can really kill the command after ctrl-z by typing ```kill -9 %%```. This even works for commands which do not terminate on ctrl-c like ```less```.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm still learning about this, but perhaps because of this certain configuration file, I have tried Control+C but the screen is unresponsive. What I am trying to install is an astronomy program and it is tied to another astronomy software. I have found that I need to type "log out" to stop the script. Just in case, I was wondering, would rebooting the computer the surest way to stop a ./configuration script? I just want to make sure I don't have any ./configuration scripts running in the background. Thank you again.

Comment: @rudimeier Thank you, that's just what I was wondering right now! I will try it.

Comment: @Guest: Note that crtl-c or `kill` without `-9` is usually the better way to terminate a process. `kill -9` should be used only if the "nice termination" does not work.